# Ionic refresh notices were wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework

How can I update this method that brings the news from time to time?

This is my cods:

```
export class HomePage {
api_url:string='http://despertadorlavalle.com.ar/wp-json/wp/v2/posts…';
posts:any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public http:Http) {
this.getNotices();

}

ionViewDidLoad(){
console.log('ionViewDidLoad HomePage');

}

getNotices(){
this.http.get(this.api_url)
.map(res => res.json()).subscribe(posts =>{
this.posts=posts;
})
}

}
```

Comment: Update it how? Do you mean periodically re-run getNotices() to reload posts from the API, i.e. update the display? (I assume you have a view that displays your posts variable already.) Or do you mean update the code somehow?

Comment: yes!  Re-run getNotices() to reload posts from the API

Comment: You mean you wan it to refresh at a certain interval?